# Wrist pain when bent back

Tags: pain, wrist

I get quite a strong pain in my wrist when I bend it back, or play a wrist-intensive sport like squash, but the rest of the time my wrist is OK and my fingers don't feel any different either.  The pain is most severe when my wrist is in this position, with the painful area circled in red:

[image: Wrist pain bend]

... so it is bent back and something is having to support it from moving any further.  For example, leaning against a wall with that hand is quite painful.  The pain is along the top of the wrist, somewhat on the ulnar side although radiating out to the whole wrist to some extent.

Is this likely to be damage to the triangular fibrocartilage?  From looking online that seems the most likely explanation.  If so what is best to heal it?  It has been this way for a few weeks now.

Comment: The wrist is too important to try and diagnose it on-line or go with the most likely explanation. The only way to get a proper answer is to be examined by a doctor in person.

Comment: Oh come on, you could say that about most parts of the body.

Comment: Yes, which is why personal medical advice is strictly off-topic.

Comment: I have an almost identical (if not actually identical) problem and had it looked at by a sports physiotherapist. She said that the damage can be to the small bones in the hand and/or the tissue which wraps the wrist (can't recall the name.) Avoid weight bearing activity which bends the hand back. I've had the problem for a long time and never completely gotten rid of recurrences, but I'm not in regular pain. Press ups on fists are a good replacement, for example. Basically, anything which keeps the hand/wrist straight, whether lifting or not.

Comment: my sister recently had this and the doctor told her it was because of her posture(it isnt that good around the neck) and she said there is a muscle connecting your neck and you wrist at the place. so really try and work on posture when sitting. i have recently gotten this in the oast couple of days and will try and sit up straighter. this totally solved my sister's pain by having better posture, no brace needed.